# Lens picker launcher Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application that needs to show the applications lens (Lens apps) function Lens Picker. To do this I am using the following call:

Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync (new Uri ("ms-lenspicker: excludedProductId = {GUID}"));

That call the native Photos app from Windows Phone to show the Lens Apps (Figure 1). I saw the behavior of the native camera that also this functionality, it does not open another application (Figure 2). I did several searches but can not find the same solution used in the native camera.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the lens picker inline, an app requires the ability to query the app metadata store on the phone to retrieve the list of apps that have registered as lenses and their icons. That capability is only available to built-in apps like Camera and Photos. The purpose of the "ms-lenspicker" URI scheme is to enable other apps to invoke the Photos app to show the picker on their behalf. In other words, it is not possible for non-Microsoft apps to render the lens picker inline.